# How to properly separate foreground from a solid colour background in an image using numpy / PIL / Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have an image given below with black background. I want to separate the background and foreground. The idea is on the assumption that the image contains **PURE Black** `[0,0,0]` only at the background part. i.e if there's any other black present in the image, it must be having a bit of `non black` too for example: `0,0,1`, `0,1,0`.. or anything else.

I tried 3 different things and got different results each time. I want to know the proper way of doing it.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
mask_color = [0,0,0]
image = np.array(Image.open('black1.PNG'))
mask = image.copy()
non_black = np.all(mask != mask_color, axis = -1) # ALL pixel which are Non-black
mask[non_black] = [255,255,255]  # Make the non black part white

Image.fromarray(mask) # show the mask
```

I also tried:

```
non_black = np.any(mask != mask_color, axis = -1) # ANY pixel which are Non-black
```

And then I tried getting a single channel whic is not so good approach because a single `0` could be anywhere.

```
mask_color = 0
image = np.array(Image.open('black1.PNG'))[:,:,0] # get only 1 channel
mask = image.copy()
mask[mask != mask_color] = 255 # set to white
```

could someone please suggest correct way of doing it?

[image]

**[Goal is to create a Black and White mask as mentioned by `@Christoph Rackwitz` in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHF4.png)**

[image]

Comment: what's the goal? this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHF4.png

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes. Absolutely. This is the Goal.  How am I supposed to achieve this?

Comment: @Deshwal `BGR to GRAY` color conversion followed by `thresholding` might solve your problem

Comment: @Bilal thanks Bilal! I just did `mask > 2`, followed by `opening -> Gaussian filter -> Thresholding` instead of `mask != [0,0,0]` and it worked. I just want to know if  my initial thinking approach is right or not.